# code/test coverage after deployment of a dotnet application

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, cypress

we are using cypress to test our deployed application (angular+ dotnetcore api), we want check if there any tools out there which would generate a coverage report similar to one that get generated when run the unit tests for both api and the ui.

we inherited this project, it does not have any unit or integrations tests, the idea is just focus on cypress tests rather than making code changes to support writing unit or integration tests.

Thanks
-Nen

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Introduction would only give you code coverage over your frontend... doubt there is a way to get the backend-part in on go though except if you additionally test the service layer seperatly

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is if you generate c# tests with the inputs of the webtests... could be done if you wrap around a decorator or pipeline around each service call... however then you only have the setup for the backend tests and no asserts. but if you go the full roundtrip (post/put etc. and then get the data and assert what you get back) you might not need the asserts for the backend. depending on the complexity of the service calls the additional work you need to put into it might vary though

Comment: do you use mediatR in your backend?

Comment: No   we do not, there are no interfaces, mocking is out of the picture